# Can't inspect corpse in Kayran lair

Tags: the-witcher-2

I have just defeated the Kayran, that stinky plague, and am searching its lair. I found a human corpse right beside a dead sheep. I am told to left click, in order to examine, but nothing happens.

1. Do you know any fix?
2. Is it important to inspect that corpse?

I am kind of reluctant to reload an early safe and try another 20-40 times to defeat that smelly Kayran...

Answer (score 1):

see here: [Goatmuncher](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Goatmuncher)

It's just little reference to the Witcher books.

Comment: Good info. Any idea why I couldn't trigger any event by searching the corps?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it triggers a comment made by Geralt concerning the story, but it can only be triggered once and I think the stuffed sheep and the cobbler share the same examination flag.